# CountDownTimer not Showing 00:00

Tags: android

i am trying countdowntimer i dont know whats wrong in this code, But countdown after coming to 00:01 stays same for next second.. i dont get 00:00 . i tried many things but were not working

CDTimer ++>

```
 public class CDTimer extends CountDownTimer {

        public CDTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
            super(startTime, interval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            String zero = tv.getText().toString();
            if(millisUntilFinished < 1950){
                tv.setText("00:00");
                }
                long seconds = (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                long minutes = seconds / 60;
                seconds = seconds % 60;
                tv.setText(String.format("%02d", minutes)
                        + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds));
            Log.d("Time", String.valueOf(timeRemain));


            timeRemain = millisUntilFinished;

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            if (isWarmup) {
                isLow = true;
                isWarmup = false;
                isHigh = false;
                startTime = getSec() * 1000 + 1000 ;
                disp_txt.setText("Low Interval");
                cd = new CDTimer(startTime, interval);
                cd.start();
            } else if (isLow) {
                isLow = false;
                isWarmup = false;
                isHigh = true;
                startTime = getSec() * 1000 + 1000;
                disp_txt.setText("High Interval");
                cd = new CDTimer(startTime, interval);
                cd.start();
            } else if (isHigh) {
                isLow = false;
                isWarmup = true;
                isHigh = false;
                disp_txt.setText("Completed");
                tv.setText("00:00");
                start.setText("START AGAIN");
                btn_chk = 0;
                cd.cancel();

            }


        }
    }
```

timeSec() method ++>

```
private int getSec() 
{

        if (isWarmup)
            return warmup;
        else if (isLow)
            return lowint;
        else
            return highint;

    }
```

Comment: what are your starttime and interval values?

Comment: startTime = timeSec() * 1000 + 1000  and   interval = 1000

Comment: and whats the value of timeSec ?

Comment: I need to know what are the exact values you are passing to the countdown timer....

Comment: CDTimer suggests me that you have made a custom countDown timer in a separated class. please show this class....

Comment: Hi sir i have updated my code ... i am getting proper time but when it comes to 00:01, it remains same for next sec..

Comment: now I am confused...do you have implemented CDTimer twice? What´s correct now, the first CDTimer post or the second one? In the second one, you have not set `tv.setText("00:00");`

Comment: i updated the code .. i had it in second post too pls check .. i tried logging the value.. but millisUntilFinished never goes below ~2000 ms

Comment: is it possible that you are passing a wrong value via timeSec()?

Comment: and you definetely coded it like you posted above? exactly with the same order?

Comment: yes..its same...and timeSec() gets passed properly.

Comment: then read my anser below, your order is wrong, respectively you have to add an else statement....

Answer (score 1):

It´s a problem of the order of called functions. You are calling `tv.setText("00:00");` as first, but then, the next functions overwrite this, you have just to make an else statement:

```
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        String zero = tv.getText().toString();
        if(millisUntilFinished < 1950){
            tv.setText("00:00");
        }else{//put an else statement here
            long seconds = (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            long minutes = seconds / 60;
            seconds = seconds % 60;
            tv.setText(String.format("%02d", minutes)
                    + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds));
        Log.d("Time", String.valueOf(timeRemain));
        }

        timeRemain = millisUntilFinished;

    }
```

What you have done is, you set `tv.setText("00:00");` , but at the next millisecond it is overwritten by your next call

```
tv.setText(String.format("%02d", minutes)
                        + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds));
```

because you have missed the else statement. This goes faster than your eyes could see :)

Comment: This is a correct answer, there is no reason for downvote. I had yesterday massive downvote on my answers in just a view seconds. Somebody seems to be angry on me....is there some freak outside?

Answer (score 1):

try this
just change the counDownInterval to 100.

```
     new CountDownTimer(10000, 100) {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "time :" + millisUntilFinished);
                    if(millisUntilFinished <= 100){
                        onFinish();
                    }else {
                        count_down.setText(""+millisUntilFinished / 1000 );
                    }
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    showCorrect(false);
                }
            }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

`if(millisUntilFinished < 1900)`

should be

`if(millisUntilFinished < 1000)`

Comment: still getting same result.. pauses for 1 sec on 00:01..and restarts counter

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public void onFinish() {

   tv.setText("00:00");

}
```